# running SASS in VSCode

Tags: css, visual-studio-code, sass

I have installed the extension `Live SASS Compiler` (live-sass) and i am getting compilation errors when compiling valid(?) SASS.

Some of the file is still normal `CSS` and some is `SASS`, which should be compatible.

I just cant find the error here...

```css
@import "ci_template.css";

body
 font-family:calibri,sans-serif,Arial
 margin:0px
 color:var(--ci-clr-primary)

/************/
/* Header */
/************/ 

#header
 font-weight:bold
 background-color:var(--ci-clr-primary)
 color:white
 overflow: hidden
 #header-logo img
  width:var(--ci-logo-width)
  margin:var(--ci-logo-margin)
 #header-text
  line-height:100px
  font-size: 2.5em
 div
  float: left
  display: block

/************/
/* topnav */
/************/

#topnav
 overflow: hidden
 background-color: darkgrey
 a
  float: left
  display: block
  color: white
  text-align: center
  padding: 14px 16px
  text-decoration: none
  font-weight:bold
  :hover,
  :focus
   background-color: #ddd
   color: grey

[...]
```

This error appears on the live sass console when I save:

```
Compilation Error
Error: Invalid CSS after '..._template.css";': expected 1 selector or at-rule, was "body"
        on line 1 of sass/c:\xampp\htdocs\projects\archiv\general.scss
>> @import "ci_template.css";
   --------------------------^

--------------------
Watching...
--------------------
```

Comment: The underscore might be messing with things, as SASS uses underscores to define partials. Try replacing it with a hyphen

Comment: unfortunately didn't change a thing @MattHamer5

Comment: According to the **[SASS Docs](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/import)**, SASS can import plain `.css` files, but the import must not explicitly include the `.css` extension type. So try just using `"@import "ci-template";`

Comment: even without the import the error remains the same. Invalid CSS after "b": expected 1 selector or at-rule, was "body" on line 1 of sass/c:\xampp\htdocs\projects\archiv\general.scss @MattHamer5

Comment: Just noticed this; you're not using opening or closing parenthesis `{...}` or closing any of your rules with a semicolon `;`. This may be one of the reasons you're getting an error.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.

I was using a .SCSS Source-File, but with SASS Syntax in it.

Renamed the file extention, cleaned up the SCSS Syntax for SASS and now its working as intended.